# Semantic-UI Search Module OnSelect issue

Tags: semantic-ui

I have created an autocomplete input field (search addresses) using the Semantic-UI Search Module. The autocomplete itself works fine but I am experiencing a strange behaviour when trying to customize the actions using the OnSelect method.

```
$('#address_search')
              .search({
                apiSettings: {
                  url: 'ajax_search_address/{query}'
                },
                minCharacters: 4,
                maxResults: 5,
                showNoResults: true,
                type: 'category',
                searchDelay: 0,
                duration: 200,
                fields: {
                    categories: 'results',
                    categoryName: 'state',
                    categoryResults: 'results',
                    description:'city',
                },
                onSearchQuery: function(query){
                    $('#address_search').addClass("loading");
                },
                onResults: function (response){
                    $('#address_search').removeClass("loading");
                },
                onSelect: function(result, response) {
                    address = result.title + ', ' + result.city + ' ' + result.region;
                    $('#address_search').search('set value', address);
                    //$('#address_search').find('input').val(address);
                    $('#address_search').search('hide results');
                    $('#address_search').removeClass("loading");

                    return false;
                },
              });
```

The reason I am using a custom OnSelect method is to display the address result in a particular way (different from how it is returned).
The problem I am facing is that it seems that when I select the address from the returned list, it calls 'set value' correctly but then seems to generate a new ajax call with the new value, hence presenting a new drop down with this address again (on its own).
As shown in the call above I tried to manually assign the value to the input field using jQuery (instead of calling 'set value') but again the behavior is the same.

I tried to use the 'cancel query' method just after to try to cancel this last ajax call when selecting the value but it does not seem to have any effect (and I'd rather avoid the unnecessary call).

Does anyone know how to prevent this? The default onSelect method (when set to 'return true' does not show this behaviour so I assume there is a way to prevent that but I haven't been able to find it based on the documentation or other threads about the subject.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The default onSelect method (when set to 'return true' does not show this behaviour

Just setting `return false` to `return true` prevents it from making another call.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The problem is that `return true` triggers the default action (from semantic doc: "The function should return false to prevent default action (closing search results and selecting value)"). In this case I am trying to display the value with a particular format (as per variable `address`). If I use `return true` then it shows the default formatting once picking up a value, overwriting the format I defined. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: You try using `setTimeout` and then return true to set a timer for 10 miliseconds and then change the value of the dropdown inside the timeout.

Comment: It seems it did the trick! Not sure it's super clean but best solution so far! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble writing a specific value to the search field after a result was selected.

I was using the setTimeout() method to avoid semantic's default behavior of overwriting my value, but it would change the value to the title field and then quickly back to what I wanted, so I came here looking for a better way.

Joshua's answer led me down the right path, and this is what ended up working for me. `return false` worked to prevent anything else from happening, and adding `'hide results'` was the only additional behavior I wanted:

```
onSelect: function (result, response) {
    doSomethingWithResult(result)
    $(".ui.search").search('hide results')
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for multiple input fields along with using **setTimeout** to fill them in with a different field:

```
    $(".ui.input.search").search({
    type: "standard",
    minCharacters: 2,
    onSelect: function onSelect(result, response) {
        console.log(result);
        setTimeout(()=>{
            $(this).search('set value', result.address);
        },10);
    },
```

As you can see, using `$(this)` along with the arrow function `()=>{` allows it to fill in the corresponding input box that was clicked, and since true is return automatically all that is needed is the **setTimeout**